# Apply transformation to a column of a vector depending on value in other column (R)

Tags: r, matrix

I'm aware this might be a VERY easy question, but i'm new at R and have been trying to find this for hours now, with no luck...

I want to apply a transformation on each element of the first column of the following matrix only if the value of the second column is 1...

```
> a<-matrix(c(30,40,50,60,1,0,1,0),nrow=4,ncol=2)
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   30    1
[2,]   40    0
[3,]   50    1
[4,]   60    0
>
```

So this would yield (assuming my function would multiply by -1 the value in column 1):

```
> a.transformed
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  -30    1
[2,]   40    0
[3,]  -50    1
[4,]   60    0
```

I think this would imply the apply() function but I can't seem to get the if() to work! Help!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[` operator to do logical comparison, and then the `[<-` operator to subset and replace relevant values...

```
#  rows we want to change
id <- a[,2] == 1
a[id , 1 ] <- a[ id , 1 ] * -1
a
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  -30    1
#[2,]   40    0
#[3,]  -50    1
#[4,]   60    0
```

I suggest reading an [**introductory text**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) as this is some rather fundamental operations in R.

Comment: Thank you (I was missing the "==" part!) Will do!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `ifelse`

```
a[,1]<-ifelse(a[,2]==1,a[,1]*-1,a[,1])
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  -30    1
[2,]   40    0
[3,]  -50    1
[4,]   60    0
```